# Django notifications not a valid choice

Tags: django, django-forms

I´m having problems with Django notifications. When trying to save a notice setting in Django admin I´m getting following error:

[image]

Unfortunately I´m not familiar with Django Backend forms. For me this looks like the send value for medium is different than the expected medium type defined in models.py. The medium is defined here.

```
medium = models.CharField(_("medium"), max_length=1, choices=NOTICE_MEDIA)
```

https://github.com/GeoNode/geonode-notification/blob/master/notification/models.py#L90

What steps are needed to get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can add to `NOTICE_MEDIA`

```
(None, '')
```

The empty choice is `None`, when `-------` is rendered its mean it's the default Blank value :)

Comment: Yeah great this sounds logic. Can you see where NOTICE_MEDIA should be extended? In models.py it´s defined here: https://github.com/GeoNode/geonode-notification/blob/master/notification/models.py#L23

Comment: Hi MaximeK, I checked the header unfortunately it seems the problem is somewhere else. The header is sending media 0 and the list of NOTICE_MEDIA has a key with 0 the empty value is not send (sorry for the bad screenshot). Maybe I do not see the forest because of trees ...

Comment: if yes you need to change `medium = models.CharField` and add `null = True` like that : `medium = models.CharField(_("medium"), max_length=1, choices=NOTICE_MEDIA, null = True)` so with that you can save your model with '-------' value

Comment: Hi Maxime I´ve migrated I´ll try your second comment thanks!

Comment: Hey Maxime, thanks a lot for your help I´ve changed the model and run `python manage.py syncdb` unfortunately this does not solve the problem. When sending the form POST has `Content-Disposition: form-data; name="medium" 0 ` this is coming from `<option value="0" selected="selected">email</option>`which both looks correct. But it seams django has no value 0 in `choices=NOTICE_MEDIA` the strange thing is, when I check NOTICE_MEDIA it´s a list like `(('0','email'))` means it´s there. Any clue what else could be go wrong here?